# Is there a way to adjust size of an externally imported image (png) through RMarkdown when the output in powerpoint_presentation

Tags: r-markdown, png, powerpoint

Using the following code in a chunk in RMarkdown (output: powerpoint_presentation), the out.width (or fig.width) does not work to change the size of the image in the powerpoint output.

```
knitr::include_graphics("folder_location/image.png")
```

Is there any way to adjust a external image?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/powerpoint-presentation.html#), this should work:

```
---
title: "pptx of images"
author: ""
date: ""
output: powerpoint_presentation
---

![caption](image.png){width=80%}
```

... except it doesn't. The image is not resized here (on Mac).